# How can I get text on UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

If I use a UIPickerView with custom View(3 components) .How could I get each text on UIPickerView from each selectedRow??

THANKS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use picker's delegate method

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

    if(component==0)
    {
        int i=row;      //here i returns the row selected by you in picker component 0
    }
    else if(component==1)
    {
        int j=row;      //here j returns the row selected by you in picker component 1
    }
    else if(component==2)
    {
        int k=row;      //here k returns the row selected by you in picker component 2
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you decide to place the text into the components.

For example, if you use `myArray`:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[myArray objectAtIndex:row]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur method, But I not only use 1 Array in each component,
component2 and 3 with Multiarray .